# TextBlock.Foreground analogue for UWP/WinUI

Tags: uwp, styles, winui, windows-app-sdk

Is it possible to globally set Foreground for Border for internal controls? Similar to WPF `TextBlock.Foreground` attached property. I tried this code, it doesn't work:

```xml
<Border.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAltMediumHighBrush"
        Color="Black"
        />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="SystemControlForegroundAltHighBrush"
        Color="Black"
        />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush"
        Color="Black"
        />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush"
        Color="Black"
        />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush"
        Color="Black"
        />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush"
        Color="Black"
        />
    <SolidColorBrush
        x:Key="SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumLowBrush"
        Color="Black"
        />
</Border.Resources>
```

I also tried `DefaultTextForegroundThemeBrush` and `SystemColorWindowTextColor`

P.S. I'll explain the reasons a little - I'm writing a utility to translate WPF xaml code into the equivalent UWP / WinUI, and I'm looking for an alternative without redefining styles (because internal controls can explicitly set their own). So far, the only solution I see is to explicitly set the Foreground property on all TextBlocks inside the Border if it's not set.

Comment: As an alternative, you could create a custom `Border` control that iterates through the `TextBlock` elements and programmatically set the `Foreground` property of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to globally set Foreground for Border for internal controls?

I have to say the answer is No. There is no way to globally change the system color just applies to a Border and its children. You could only override the system color in the `Application.Resources` from the App.Xaml. And this will affect all the controls in the app that uses this color.

For your scenario, I'd suggest you change the `Foreground` property of these child controls in the Border control.

Like this:

```
 <Border>
        <Border.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
            </Style>
        </Border.Resources>
         <!--red text-->
        <TextBlock Text="2132123314132133143123314213412343" />
</Border>
     <!--black text-->
    <TextBlock Text="2132123314132133143123314213412343" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll wait for alternatives. I also added a little explanation of why to the end of my question.